# Usage of a part of a EPL library in LGPL or Apache 2 project

Tags: apache-2.0, lgpl, linked-libraries, epl, package

As I understand it, I am allowed to link a eclipse licensed jar to an LGPL or Apache 2 licensed open source project, without to change the projects license.  Correct me if I am wrong.

The question is, may I take only a part (classes of one package instead of all) from the EPL jar and pack it together in the targets jar file?

It's only a matter of target projects size.